# Integrate REST API SDK Php for PayPal with Code Igniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I need to use [rest-api-sdk-php](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php) in Code Igniter project. I read the docs and first problem is Code Igniter don't use composer approach so I have downloaded the library as a .zip file and put inside `library` folder. Now the problem is that the SDK uses OOP approach and Code Igniter doesn't or not at all then how do I integrate the library to my project?

**Get errors while trying to use the library**

I'm trying to use the library in my module (PyroCMS module) and I did as follow:

```
include SHARED_ADDONPATH . 'libraries/paypal/config.php';
include SHARED_ADDONPATH . 'libraries/paypal/autoload.php';

$PayPal = new \angelleye\PayPal\Adaptive($PayPalConfig);
```

But I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'angelleye\PayPal\Adaptive' not found in
>   /var/www/html/alomicuba/addons/shared_addons/modules/payment/controllers/payment.php
>   on line 51

So I think autoloading isn't working, any help?

Comment: We got you all fixed up now, right?

Comment: @AndrewAngell almost, I only have one doubt, since my account isn't Business or Premier, which kind of payment should I use? `Pay` doesn't work since it works with Adaptive and that requires the account type I mention before, should I use instead `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`?

Comment: What do you have against updating the account?  Express Checkout is going to require an updated account as well.

Comment: @AndrewAngell around your doubt I send you a private email answering that and since I'm using your library within CI project I change a bit things and this are the only required parameters for PayPal config library? `Sandbox, DeveloperAccountEmail, ApplicationID, DeviceID, IPAddress, APIUsername, APIPassword, APISignature, APISubject`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter is indeed an OOP platform.  Not sure why you would say otherwise..??  You can [use Composer with CodeIgniter](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2012/05/composer-with-codeigniter), too.

I would recommend using the Classic API instead of REST, though.  The REST API is much newer and not nearly as mature as the classic API.  You'll probably run into things you want to do later that REST simply doesn't provide yet, and then you'll need classic anyway.

On that note, I have a [PayPal library specific to CodeIgniter](http://www.angelleye.com/download-codeigniter-php-library-for-paypal-payments-pro/) you might be interested in.  It's slightly out-dated because I have stopped maintaining that so that I can focus on my [general PayPal PHP library](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/), which has been updated to work with (or without) Composer.  Again, though, it could be used in CodeIgniter, or you could just use the CI specific library, which does contain pretty much everything the classic API's have to offer.

So, if you're familiar with CodeIgniter libraries already I'd probably recommend just going with that one.  I would definitely recommend getting familiar with Composer, though, and eventually making the jump from CI to Laravel.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PayPal at all so in order to work with your general PayPal PHP library and made a simple payment what is the flow to follow? Did you have any example to look in?

Comment: You obviously didn't read the documentation that comes with the library.  ;)  Take a look at that.  It points you to a demo, samples, etc.  If you have more questions then I'm happy to help.

Comment: As for the flow (which API calls to make) are you just trying to integrate PayPal payment options, or are you trying to do direct credit card processing, or what exactly?